# using ethernet port for transferring data and updating firmware

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader

I use PIC18F97J60 because its ethernet port to exchange data via lan cable. I want to update the firmware of the mcu using the same port which means using bootloader for the port. Is making a bootloader for ethernet port means that the port is dedicated for only updating firmare no more no less ? Or it can be used for both transfering data between the MCU and the server and updating firmware at the same time ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is making a bootloader for ethernet port means that the port is
>   dedicated for only updating firmare no more no less ?

No.  The firmware will receive the firmware update via the Ethernet port but the program can still use the Ethernet port for other things.

> Or it can be used for both transfering data between the MCU and the
>   server and updating firmware at the same time ?

Yes.  It seems unusual to me that a device would need to send data and receive a firmware update *simultaneously*, but I guess it's possible.  It seems more common that the device would have different operating modes for producing/sending data and updating the firmware.  The server would send a firmware update command to switch modes and the device would stop sending data and start receiving the firmware update.  The same port could be used for sending data and receiving the firmware update.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: But do you think there is a bootloader for ethernet provided by microship or i have to develop one